# Error while configuring mirroring, Microsoft SQL Server, error : 1418

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 Enterprise SP1 installed on my both principle and mirror server. SQL Server and SQL Server agent service is also started by same ID having sysadmin rights.

But when I am trying to establish mirroring between them, it is reflecting an error message, Microsoft SQL Server, Error:1418

I have checked the endpoint of both server that are in started state. and also dropped and create endpoints again. please note i am not using the witness server here.

- Principle server endpoint port:- 5022
- mirror server endpoint port :- 5023
- mirror server at endpoint port 5022 also didn't work.
- Both 5022 and 5023 ports are opened on firewall

but when I execute the following script on both server, asynchronous(high safety mode) mirroring established.

```
TO SETUP MIRRORING in synchronous(high safty) ON PRINCIPLE SERVER:-
ALTER DATABASE SMPP
SET PARTNER = 'TCP://principle server IP:5022'

TO SETUP MIRRORING ON MIRROR SERVER:-
ALTER DATABASE SMPP
SET PARTNER = 'TCP://mirror server ip:5023'
```

I also tried to put hostname of principle and mirror server instance in above script but no luck.

Please suggest any working solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft error no 1418:-
this error occurs due to communication problem between endpoints.first of all you have to check TCP/IP for the instance was enabled or not,if any duplicate endpoints exists,in 
case login was not created inn the other instances of mirroring pair,check for the edition of principal and mirror servers.

Comment: This is not the answer plz delete it and add it in your question